# Are all fonts will take same space on browser with same value?

Tags: css, xhtml, fonts

Are all fonts size would be same with same value?

for example `p { font-family:Arial; font-size:12px}`

if i change Arial to any other font then will all fonts will render in same size as Arial render in 12px, in all browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: No.

I'm not entirely sure of the historical reason for this, though here's [one example](http://nwalsh.com/comp.fonts/FAQ/cf_8.htm#SEC16) of the convoluted history that you're dealing with if you want to understand typography in detail.

As empirical proof of this answer, try pasting this code into a text file and opening the file in a browser:

```
<div style="font-family:Arial; font-size:12px">This is 12 point type.</div><br />
<div style="font-family:Times New Roman; font-size:12px">This is 12 point type.</div><br />
```

Comment: I found what seems like a [cleaner write-up](http://www.oberonplace.com/dtp/fonts/fontsize.htm) of the issue, and even then it's convoluted and beyond my patience to untangle.

I suspect the short answer is: "Evolution is messy."

Answer (score 0):

Well, it will most likely render differently on Windows vs. OS X, even if it is the same font.